# Read Sub directory and specific files in Java

Tags: java, spring

I need find all the java files in a directory

```
    private void search(File directory) {
        if (directory.isDirectory()) {
            File[] javaFilesLs = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                  return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".java");
//                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".java") || dir.isDirectory();
                }
            });
            if (directory.canRead()) {
                assert javaFilesLs != null;
                for (File temp : javaFilesLs) {
                    if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                        search(temp);
                    } else {
                        fileList.add(temp.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I use the commented line it finds the subdirectory and all the files not only `".java"` files.

Comment: `public boolean accept(File dir, String name)...` - _dir_ here refers to the parent directory the file was found in, so for all `dir.isDirectory()`, this will be true. [FilenameFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html)

Comment: `||` means **or**, you need to use `&&` which means **and**

Comment: What is your end goal with this? Trying to read all the files that end with .java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get all paths using the commented line, is that `dir.isDirectory()` will return `true` for all files.
Take a look at the documentation of [FilenameFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html). It specifies that `dir` is *"the directory in which the file was found."*

So instead of looking at `dir`, you must test if `name` represents a directory. There may be smarter methods, but it can be done like this:

```
new File(dir.toPath().toString(), name).isDirectory() // returns true for directories
```

The whole snippet thus looks like this:

```
private void search(File directory) {
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        File[] javaFilesLs = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".java") || new File(dir.toPath().toString(), name).isDirectory();
            }
        });
        if (directory.canRead()) {
            assert javaFilesLs != null;
            for (File temp : javaFilesLs) {
                if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                    search(temp);
                } else {
                    fileList.add(temp.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, Java 8 adds [Files.walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) which implements the recursion for you as a Stream.

```
private void search(File directory) throws IOException {
    Files.walk(directory.toPath())
        .filter(f -> {
            return f.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".java");
        })
        .forEach(f -> fileList.add(f.toFile().getAbsolutePath()));
}
```